# Subprocess, Controlling cmd input

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, console, subprocess, popen

I´m new to python and the forum.

At the moment, I´m coding a tool in PyCharm.
This tool should navigate my smartphone by UiAutomator to a specific screen an push a button. After pushing this button, an external (.bat) should start and the root-programm should wait until it finishes.
The journey through the smartphone-screens works well. But calling the subprocess makes difficulties.
So much for that context.

The .bat will start a cmd.exe and wait for some input (mostly a number and a push on the Enter-Button)
I´m starting the .bat by:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import os
proc = Popen(["Test.bat"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

After the call for "proc", the correct content is displayed on the console and the tool is waiting for my input.
Can you tell me, how I can generate input to the console and confirm it by enter?

I searched many websites and didn´t find a proper way to help.
Thanks in advance, hope you can help.

EDIT:
Unfortunately I´m not allowed to provide the batch-file, but I can give an example of the input-request:
The inputs of the .bat are requested in this kind:

```
set /p choice=What do you want to do ('e' for exit)? 
IF /I "%choice%"=="1" goto fetchJobs
IF /I "%choice%"=="e" exit /b
```

The input is totally processed by the .bat. So there is nothing to do but providing "1" as input and waiting for the process to end.

The issue is, that I don´t know how to provide this input to the request when the batch-file is called as subprocess.

Comment: What is the content of `Test.bat`, we need to know how it requests input, and what you're doing with that input once received. At the moment there is nothing in your question to link it with the batch file, so we're unable to reproduce the issue you are experiencing, and therefore assist you with it. Please do not respond to my comment by adding the required information to another comment, use the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66029246/edit), and include it in your question area itself.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] of your batch file, then explain exactly what the issue is, so that we can each experience the same situation. The batch file doesn't need to have the exact content, just the same syntax and character inputs etc, the creation of the variables, and how it outputs to be received in your python code. This site is a technical one, we cannot guess what you're doing, and currently it is not clear. BTW, you shouldn't be using `set /p` to receive your input, you should be using the `choice.exe` utility. That returns an errorlevel, which may be simpler to process directly.

Comment: Problem is, that this batch tool is usually a command window tool which is controlled manually. 
Now there should be an automatic process for testing. 
That´s why I was trying to automate the input given to the command window tool. 
Manually you do this by entering the required input ("1" in the example above) and pressing the enter-button.

Comment: Now I tried to call this command window tool by "subprocess" and provide the inputs. Hope this explains halfways.

Comment: Example `choice.exe /C FE /M "FetchJobs, or Exit"`, followed by `Exit /B %ErrorLevel%`, where your python code would receive an exit code of `1` for `FetchJobs` and an exit code of `2` for `Exit`.

Comment: Sorry, let mit clarify:
My pythoncode doesn´t require any exitcodes. The batch command window tool requires some input from the python code (e. g. "1" -> Enter)

Comment: I never said you did! What I'm telling you is that you shouldn't really need a batch file at all for perfroming that task, but as you appear to have oher things in it, it would be simpler to deal with the different entries within your python code instead of in your batch file. Even if you were using a series of `if`/`else` conditions in your batch file, as you're simply asking for known menu like entries, choice.exe is still the correct way to do it, not `set /p`. Choice accepts only known single input keys, whereas `set /p` accepts anything or nothing, including typos, and malicious entries.

Comment: The advice I'm providing is not an answer to your question, otherwise it would be in the answer area, I am now aware that you're batch file is not communicating back the input prompts to your python code, but I'm still giving you advice on how to improve you batch file robustness. Example lines: `Echo 1. Fetch Jobs`, `Echo 2. Something Else`, `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12E /N "Select an item number, or press [E] to exit"`, `If ErrorLevel 3 Exit /B`, `If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo SomethingElse`, `:FetchJobs`.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyways. 
I´ll keep that in mind to improve the batch.